# How to convert this type of json response into User defined types

Tags: c#, json, web-services, api, user-defined-types

I am using a web service which returns data into JSON in following format

```
{
    "responseId": 2933574,
    "availableHotels": [
        {
            "processId": "HC-65870953",
            "hotelCode": "UKI9E6",
            "availabilityStatus": "InstantConfirmation",
            "totalPrice": 971,
            "totalTax": 0,
            "totalSalePrice": 0,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "boardType": "Bed & Continental Breakfast",
            "rooms": [
                {
                    "roomCategory": "Triple Room",
                    "paxes": [
                        {
                            "paxType": "Adult",
                            "age": 30
                        },
                        {
                            "paxType": "Adult",
                            "age": 30
                        },
                        {
                            "paxType": "Child",
                            "age": "6"
                        }
                    ],
                    "totalRoomRate": 486,
                    "ratesPerNight": [
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-20",
                            "amount": 163
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-21",
                            "amount": 163
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-22",
                            "amount": 160
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-23",
                            "amount": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "roomCategory": "Triple Room",
                    "paxes": [
                        {
                            "paxType": "Adult",
                            "age": 30
                        },
                        {
                            "paxType": "Adult",
                            "age": 30
                        },
                        {
                            "paxType": "Child",
                            "age": "8"
                        }
                    ],
                    "totalRoomRate": 485,
                    "ratesPerNight": [
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-20",
                            "amount": 163
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-21",
                            "amount": 163
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-22",
                            "amount": 160
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-23",
                            "amount": -1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "processId": "HH-22003963",
            "hotelCode": "UKPDNN",
            "availabilityStatus": "InstantConfirmation",
            "totalPrice": 1085,
            "totalTax": 0,
            "totalSalePrice": 0,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "boardType": "Bed and Breakfast",
            "rooms": [
                {
                    "roomCategory": "Triple Room",
                    "paxes": [
                        {
                            "paxType": "Adult",
                            "age": 30
                        },
                        {
                            "paxType": "Adult",
                            "age": 30
                        },
                        {
                            "paxType": "Child",
                            "age": "6"
                        }
                    ],
                    "totalRoomRate": 544,
                    "ratesPerNight": [
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-20",
                            "amount": 136
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-21",
                            "amount": 136
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-22",
                            "amount": 136
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-23",
                            "amount": 136
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "roomCategory": "Triple Room",
                    "paxes": [
                        {
                            "paxType": "Adult",
                            "age": 30
                        },
                        {
                            "paxType": "Adult",
                            "age": 30
                        },
                        {
                            "paxType": "Child",
                            "age": "8"
                        }
                    ],
                    "totalRoomRate": 541,
                    "ratesPerNight": [
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-20",
                            "amount": 136
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-21",
                            "amount": 136
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-22",
                            "amount": 136
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-07-23",
                            "amount": 133
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "totalFound": 2,
    "searchId": "QG-67623913"
}
```

Now I have a class defined as following:

```
 public class getAvailableHotelResponse
    {
        public getAvailableHotelResponse();

        public hotel[] availableHotels { get; set; }
        [SoapElement(DataType = "integer")]
        public string responseId { get; set; }
        public string searchId { get; set; }
        [SoapElement(DataType = "integer")]
        public string totalFound { get; set; }
    }
```

And the `hotel` class is as follows:

```
public class hotel
    {
        public hotel();

        public string availabilityStatus { get; set; }
        public string boardType { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string hotelCode { get; set; }
        public string processId { get; set; }
        public roomResponse[] rooms { get; set; }
        [SoapElement(DataType = "integer")]
        public string specialDeal { get; set; }
        public float totalPrice { get; set; }
        [SoapIgnore]
        public bool totalPriceSpecified { get; set; }
        public float totalSalePrice { get; set; }
        [SoapIgnore]
        public bool totalSalePriceSpecified { get; set; }
        public float totalTax { get; set; }
        [SoapIgnore]
        public bool totalTaxSpecified { get; set; }
    }
```

And the `roomResponse` class is as follows:

```
public class roomResponse
    {
        public roomResponse();

        public pax[] paxes { get; set; }
        public dailyRate[] ratesPerNight { get; set; }
        public string roomCategory { get; set; }
        public float totalRoomRate { get; set; }
        [SoapIgnore]
        public bool totalRoomRateSpecified { get; set; }
    }
```

And `pax` class is as follows:

```
 public class pax
    {
        public pax();

        [SoapElement(DataType = "integer")]
        public string age { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string paxType { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
```

And `dailyRate` class is as follows:

```
 public class dailyRate
    {
        public dailyRate();

        public float amount { get; set; }
        [SoapIgnore]
        public bool amountSpecified { get; set; }
        [SoapElement(DataType = "date")]
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        [SoapIgnore]
        public bool dateSpecified { get; set; }
    }
```

**Edit**

```
getAvailableHotelResponse h = new getAvailableHotelResponse();

h = (getAvailableHotelResponse)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
```

I tried this and it's throwing the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type
>   'hotelspro.getAvailableHotelResponse'.

There is a really complex structure of JSON, so how do I convert this to my objects?

Comment: Please mark things up ***properly***. I've fixed the JSON markup for you on this occasion, but with 85 answers and 51 questions, really you should be doing this right yourself.

Comment: Separately: ***What have you tried***?

Comment: i dont know who downvote but i tried Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and   DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(getAvailableHotels));
                object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
                getAvailableHotels jsonResponse = objResponse as getAvailableHotels;

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i have edited question and also edit my try . I never post any question with out surfing at least two hours stackoverflow for similar questions

Comment: IF you've tried something then why not put it in the question?

Comment: @GeorgePotter i already put it here ,check edited section please.everywhere i just found that use NewTonSoft JSON library and i try to use this but error :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove non-compilable constructors like `public pax();` and just use

```
var availHotels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<getAvailableHotelResponse>(text);
```

that's all.

In fact, you wouldn't even need to declare this bunch of classes(`getAvailableHotelResponse`, `hotel`,`roomResponse`,`pax`,`dailyRate` etc.) if you made use of [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). For ex,

```
dynamic response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);

foreach (var hotel in response.availableHotels)
{
    Console.WriteLine(hotel.processId);
    foreach (var room in hotel.rooms)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + room.roomCategory);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i have to join two different results , One from databse and One from API response.thats the reason i had made this buch of classes. HotelId is present in both place (API,DB) and HotelName is only available in DB .

Comment: @rahularyansharma , Have you read the first part of my answer? you have an almost-correct  code. Then forget the `dynamic` part and go your way.

Comment: Problem is that these classes are not written by me , these are soap classes which are included by web references so i cant make any changes in them ...... should i write same classes by me .... is there any other way i can use those classes

Comment: @rahularyansharma you will have to edit these classes since `public pax();` is not compilable.

Comment: @How can i edit web references soap  classes . I can show there meta data when i use  go to reference ....

Comment: If you set `Show all files` option in solution explorer, you can find related `.cs` file.

Comment: is it possible to come on chat as these comments are going no where and list is becoming too long

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time when I work on frameworks that provide response, they have at the VERY least a standardized response.

And what response may be generic, but I know what to expect.  So it's not uncommon to receive a broad response such as:

```
{
   'data': 'JSON-blah-JSON-blah-IneedAcocktail-JSON-blah',
   'status': 200,
   'fortune': 'shakeHarder'
}
```

Understanding that generic response and then using it to reflect what you need later might be the case.

For instance, all of the objects you're receiving are objects you already use.  There might be things like a pax number you don't know normally..inherit it and the other standardized random things that don't need to conflict.

Then create a container class that encompasses the object you need.  Perhaps you need to translate it into your formatting; but at least you have it in the format you know how to work with and you're not parsing strings until you're blue.